# If $P$ is the standard matrix for an orthogonal projection, $P = P^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am having trouble with understanding the following step.

> Given that 
>   $$
> P= M(M^TM)^{-1}M^T,
> $$
>   we have that
>   $$
> P^T= (M(M^TM)^{-1}M^T)^T=M(M^TM)^{-1}M^T=P.
> $$

I understand that since we have that $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$, clearly $(MM^T)^T=MM^T$.

However, why is it that $((M^TM)^{-1})^T = (M^TM)^{-1}$?

Is $(M^TM)^{-1}$ symmetric?

Comment: I guess you're only missing $(M^{-1})^T=(M^T)^{-1}$ which is easy to prove: $M^T(M^{-1})^T=(M^{-1}M)^T=I^T=I$.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you! This was what I needed.
So  $((M^TM)^{-1})^T = (M^{-1}(M^{-1})^T)^T =M^{-1}(M^{-1})^T = (M^TM)^{-1}$ is what I guess is going on.

Comment: yes, or even: $((M^TM)^{-1})^T=((M^TM)^T)^{-1}=(M^TM)^{-1}$.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You put it a lot more elegantly :P As a saying goes where I hail from, one only sees as much as they know. Thank you again. you've been so much help!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Sorry to be a bother, but if you wouldn't mind one more question: what happens in the case that $M$ is not a square matrix (when $M^{-1}$ is undefined)? Then how would one go about evaluating $((M^TM)^{-1})^T$?

Comment: $(^{\mathrm t\!}M M)^{-1}\,$ is symmetric because $\,^{\mathrm t\!}M M\,$ is.

Comment: as @Bernard said, if $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then $A^{-1}$ is also symmetric (since, again $(A^{-1})^T=(A^T)^{-1}=A^{-1}$). The line I wrote above: $((M^TM)^{-1})^T=((M^TM)^T)^{-1}=(M^TM)^{-1}$ is valid even for non-square matrices $M$; it is valid under the only condition that $M^TM$ is invertible.